# Getting AttributeError while using create_all in test case

Tags: python, flask-sqlalchemy, pytest

I have the below fixtures in my conftest as below:

```
@pytest.fixture(scope='session')
def test_database():
    return 'sqlite:///'

@pytest.fixture(scope='session')
def database_info(test_database):
   yield db, test_database, None

@pytest.yield_fixture(scope='session')
def app_instance(database_info):
from abcr.webapp import create_app
db = list(database_info).pop(0)
app = create_app(
    db_instance=db,
    testing=True
)

yield app
```

In my testcase I am using the fixture as below:

```
@pytest.mark.usefixtures('app_instance')
class UtilsTest(unittest.TestCase):

@pytest.fixture(scope='session')
def init_db(self, database_info, app_instance):
    app = app_instance
    db = database_info
    with app.app_context():
        db.create_all()
```

I am getting below error:  AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'create_all'
I am unable to figure out the reason.

Comment: i think that your `database_info` is tuple not instance

Comment: ok what do I need to do to make an instance of it?

Comment: `app_instance ` isn't it your instance? i am confused. Oh i see 
you need to write just `db, test_database, _ = database_info`

Comment: Yes typing `db` does not mean you got `db` from your tuple

Comment: ok i made the changes you asked me to make and got a different error: 
sqlalchemy.exc.ArgumentError: Could not parse rfc1738 URL from string 'test'

Comment: I am not sure where it is picking 'test' from, maybe the configs. Not sure what should be there in place of 'test'